# Regex expression to isolate particular part of string

Tags: php, regex

I'm struggling to find the correct regular expression to return:

```
'industry =[[Banking]], [[Financial services]] |products = [[Investment Banking]]'
```

from the following:

```
<?php
$x =  '[[Basel]] |key_people = [[Axel A. Weber]] (Chairman){{br}}[[Sergio  
Ermotti]] (CEO) {{br}} |area_served = Worldwide |industry =[[Banking]],   
[[Financial services]] |products = [[Investment Banking]]';
';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match` to garb the last two parts of `|` delimited text.

```
preg_match('~(?<=\|)[^|]*\|[^|]*$~', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mN7oE5/3)

Comment: thanks alot however I was really trying to match the industry in a longer block of text seen in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066282/preg-match-all-not-returning-expected-values?noredirect=1#comment52030149_32066282

Comment: But this answers your current question.