# Download Wikidata single entity - truthy

Tags: rdf, wikidata, reification

I would like to download Wikidata for a single entity. I know I can achieve using the URL, for example:

`https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q42.rdf`

Will give me Wikidata for **Douglas Adams** in RDF format.

But this data is fully, meaning complete with meta-data such as qualifiers and references. I am interested in primary data only.

Actually I am working on RDF Reification, and for that I need some sample non-RDF data which I can test my program on (like truthy Wikidata).

I do not wish to download entire Wikidata dumps (Which I know are available in truthy format).

Comment: Try `?flavor=simple`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359335/wikidata-content-negotiation

Comment: BTW, it's not very accurate to say that truthy statements are primary, whereas full statements are derivated; quite the contrary. Truthy statements represent full statements that have the best non-deprecated rank for given property.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Ohh, good to know. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`.ttl?flavor=simple`** produces also many sitelinks which look like this:

```
<https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Адамс,_Дуглас> a schema:Article ;
    schema:about wd:Q42 ;
    schema:inLanguage "ru" ;
    schema:isPartOf <https://ru.wikipedia.org/> ;
    schema:name "Адамс, Дуглас"@ru .

<https://ru.wikipedia.org/> wikibase:wikiGroup "wikipedia" .
```

If you want to get rid of them, you can manually [`CONSTRUCT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct) what you want as described below.

Do not forget to send `Accept: text/turtle`.

**Truthy statements, without properties from external vocabularies**

```
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o} WHERE {
  VALUES (?s) {(wd:Q42)}
  ?s ?p ?o . 
  [] wikibase:directClaim ?p 
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#CONSTRUCT%20%7B%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fs%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ42%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%20%0A%20%20%5B%5D%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fp%20%0A%7D)

**Truthy statements, with properties from external vocabularies**

```
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o} WHERE {
  VALUES (?s) {(wd:Q42)}
  ?s ?p ?o . 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { [] wikibase:claim|wikibase:directClaimNormalized ?p }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#CONSTRUCT%20%7B%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fs%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ42%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%5B%5D%20wikibase%3Aclaim%7Cwikibase%3AdirectClaimNormalized%20%3Fp%20%7D%0A%7D)

---

[Documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Predicates)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332839/download-wikidata-single-entity-truthy#comment85668164_49332839), we can use the `?flavor=simple` like so:

`https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q42.rdf?flavor=simple`