# Retrieve properties and their descriptions from instances of the same class

Tags: properties, query-optimization, sparql, union, wikidata

I want to retrieve all distinct object properties of instances with the same type (class), starting with two initial seeds (wd:Q963 and wd:Q42320). First, I ask for the type (and maybe subtype) of such seeds. Second, all instances of the same class of the seeds are retrieved. Third, properties of the instances are retrieved. Finally, I want to retrieve descriptions of such properties and if possible alternative labels. My query is as follows:

```
select distinct ?property ?description ?label where{
  {     
    wd:Q963 wdt:P31 ?typesSubject . 
    ?instancesS (wdt:P31|wdt:P279) ?typesSubject .
    ?instancesS ?property ?unknown .
  }
 UNION
  { 
    wd:Q42320 wdt:P31 ?typesObject . 
    ?instancesO (wdt:P31|wdt:P279) ?typesObject . 
    ?unknown ?property ?instancesO . 
  }

 ?claimPredicate wikibase:directClaim ?property . 
 ?claimPredicate schema:description ?description .  
 ?claimPredicate rdfs:label ?label .  

   FILTER(strstarts(str(?property),str(wdt:)))
   FILTER(strstarts(str(?unknown),str(wd:)))

   FILTER(LANG(?description) = "en").  
   FILTER(LANG(?label) = "en"). 

}
```

The problem is that my actual query takes a lot of time and it fails in the public Wikidata endpoint. Does anyone can provide me some hints to optimize such a query?

Comment: Retrieval of the `407` properties works in ~ 3s: `select distinct ?property where{
  {     
    ?instancesS (wdt:P31|wdt:P279)/^wdt:P31 wd:Q963 .
    ?instancesS ?property ?unknown .
    FILTER(strstarts(str(?property),str(wdt:)))
  }
 UNION
  { 
    ?instancesO (wdt:P31|wdt:P279)/^wdt:P31  wd:Q42320 . 
    ?unknown ?property ?instancesO . 
    FILTER(strstarts(str(?unknown),str(wd:)))
  }
    }` the problem is the join with the claims

Comment: thank you @AKSW, you are right, I did not know how to address such join issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I can't understand the aim of your query. I suppose you are interested in semantic similarity or something like.

Basically, you could reduce the number of joins, retrieving only unique wdt-predicates with nested `SELECT DITINCT`.

```sql
SELECT ?property ?claimPredicateLabel ?claimPredicateDescription 
WHERE {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
  {  
  SELECT DISTINCT ?property {
    VALUES (?s) {(wd:Q963) (wd:Q42320)}
    ?s wdt:P31/^(wdt:P31|wdt:P279) ?instances .
    ?instances ?property ?unknown .
    }
  }
  ?claimPredicate wikibase:directClaim ?property . 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fproperty%20%3FclaimPredicateLabel%20%3FclaimPredicateDescription%20%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20hint%3AQuery%20hint%3Aoptimizer%20%22None%22%20.%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fproperty%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fs%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ963%29%20%28wd%3AQ42320%29%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP31%2F%5E%28wdt%3AP31%7Cwdt%3AP279%29%20%3Finstances%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Finstances%20%3Fproperty%20%20%3Funknown%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3FclaimPredicate%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fproperty%20.%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%20)

This is fast enough (~ 3s)  even with `SERVICE wikibase:label`.

Also, you [don't need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350592/7879193) `FILTER(strstarts(str(?property),str(wdt:)))` after `?claimPredicate wikibase:directClaim ?property`.

---

As for `hint:Query hint:optimizer "None"`, this hint forces Blazegraph to follow standard [bottom-up](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Bottom_Up_Semantics) evaluation order. In this particular query, `hint:Query hint:optimizer "Runtime"` or `hint:SubQuery hint:runOnce true` should [also](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints) work.

Comment: Thank you very much @Stanislav, Query hints helped a lot. Additionally, I also included the instruction `(GROUP_CONCAT(?alternative;separator="|") as ?altLabel)` together with `?claimPredicate skos:altLabel ?alternative .` and a `group by` in order to obtain all possible alternative labels of every property in the same row