# How to get only Wikidata wdt (or other) predicates for an item via SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Very new to this, so might have some terms wrong. I want to get a subset of triples for an entity (or entities). For example, this gives me 856 (as of now) triples for these two entities, including some labels and also [`/prop/direct/`, `/prop/direct-normalized/`, and `/prop/` predicates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Prefixes_used):

```
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o.}
WHERE {
VALUES ?s {wd:Q937 wd:Q670439}
{?s ?p ?o.}
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#CONSTRUCT%20%7B%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo.%7D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0AVALUES%20%3Fs%20%7Bwd%3AQ937%20wd%3AQ670439%7D%0A%7B%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo.%7D%0A%7D%0A)

But what if I only want the `/prop/direct/` (`wdt`) triples? Would I use `FILTER` in some way? I suspect I'm missing the correct way to specify these in the first place. I'd like to stick with the `CONSTRUCT` verb. Thanks.

Comment: A filter can indeed work if you don't find a triple pattern that restricts the property type to the direct ones. For example, `WHERE {
VALUES ?s {wd:Q937 wd:Q670439}
{?s ?p ?o.}
  filter(strstarts(str(?p), str(wdt:)))
}`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350592/7879193

Comment: Ah, ok. The "truthy statements with properties from external vocabularies" examples is more like what I want, but FILTER seems to slow things down a lot. `[] wikibase:directClaim ?p` is fast and one can specify alternatives like `[] wikibase:directClaim | wikibase:directClaimNormalized ?p`. Is there a way to specify alternatives including external vocabularies? My naive attempt `[] wikibase:directClaim | skos:altLabel ?p` didn't return in any altLabel triples.

Comment: In place of `[] wikibase:directClaim ?p`, you can write `{[] wikibase:directClaim ?p  } UNION {VALUES (?p) {(rdfs:label)
(skos:altLabel)
(schema:description)
(schema:dateModified)
(schema:version)
(wikibase:timestamp)
(wikibase:identifiers)
(wikibase:statements)
(wikibase:sitelinks)
(rdf:type)}}
}`. Not sure this will be faster than `FILTER NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin, this is great! It's at least 6x faster than the `FILTER NOT EXISTS` version.