# Want to get only the statement properties excluding Identifier

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to get all the properties in the statement section in the wikidata page. For example, [South Korea](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q884) there are statement, identifier and reference link (wikipedia or other link) sections respectively. I want to get the statement properties only excluding identifier and other stuff. I got all the properties with the below query but I am still struggling excluding id and other stuffs. Would you help me adding additional conditions? Thank you for your kindness in advance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?wd ?wdLabel {
  BIND (wd:Q884 AS ?subject)

  ?subject ?p ?statement .  
  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ko,en" }
} ORDER BY ?wdLabel
```

Comment: You have to use `FILTER` expressions then. Like `FILTER(?p NOT IN (p1, p2, ..., pn))`. You can also filter by some `REGEX` or `STRSTARTS` to omit all properties in some namespace

Comment: or you look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432109/how-to-get-only-wikidata-wdt-or-other-predicates-for-an-item-via-sparql

Comment: Oh, I see. It helps a lot. Thank you